# Does anyone know what this component could be?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification, components

I am currently working on an already fully assembled PCB. I want to get into Hardware Reverse Engineering and my first step would be to identify all important components.
I found most of the components via a simple Google search but there is one that I simply can't identify. 
I even tried to search for the company logo (the thing in the left upper corner, I guess that's the company logo, at least I don't know what else it could be) but I can't find anything helpfull.
This is why I am asking here, maybe someone of you knows what this can be or even knows the company :)

My suggestion btw is, that it could be the NAND Flash but I am not sure.

Picture description (in case you can't read the characters):

FP1545

5F1GQ4UCYIG

H8K094

[image]

Comment: Some contect would be helpful, maybe show us a photo pf the PCB, where the chip is used on.

Comment: I found your component on many chinese websites and all of them referenced to this datasheet https://www.endrich.com/fm/2/GD5F1GQ4UAYIG.pdf. It's a NAND flash memory with SPI interface.

Comment: Thx everyone :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a SPI(x1/x2/x4) NAND Flash from GigaDevice.

See [Datasheet GD5FxGQ4xC](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1226904/GigaDevice/GD5F1GQ4UCYIG/1)

- The 1st x: 1 stands for Density: 1 Gb
- The 2nd x: U stands for Voltage: 3.3V (2.7~3.6V)

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

It's made by GigaDevice, and it is a 1Gb NAND flash with SPI interface.
See [here](https://www.gigadevice.com/flash-memory/gd5f1gq4uc/).

Comment: Thank you very much :)